# SHIFT+F9 in macro and macro refreshing speed

Tags: vba, excel

I made two linked macros.

One of them generates copies of a certain sheet in a workbook. The problem here is that I need to press shift+f9 in all the copied sheets to update my values. I have already used calculate and application.calculate = xl......

Second macro calls the values of the first macro and performs operation on that. The problem here is that after running the first macro and using shift+f9, updating all the sheets..if I run this second macro using an assigned button it does not run but if i step into the macro and run it step by step it runs properly.

I think it's because the values of first macro take time to refresh hence this problem occurs..

Macro1:

```
Sub macro1()
Worksheets("Excel Inputs").Activate
If Sheets("Excel Inputs").Cells(11, "P") = 3 Then
    Sheets("Valuation 02").Delete
    Sheets("Valuation 03").Delete
ElseIf Sheets("Excel Inputs").Cells(11, "P") = 2 Then
    Sheets("Valuation 02").Delete
End If
Length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B13:B15"))
For i = 1 To Length - 1
    Sheets("Valuation 01").Copy After:=Sheets(4 + i)
    Sheets(4 + i + 1).Name = "Valuation 0" & (i + 1)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Next i
    Sheets("Excel Inputs").Cells(11, "P") = Length
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: So, even if you wait for a long while and then click the button, it still won't work?

Comment: That's the thing.. it doesn't.. when it click that button or even press F8 (while stepping into) too quickly it breaks.. and then when i go back to excel and check then the copied sheets(which come from macro 1) have #values.. and then again when i press Shift+f9 they update to correct values !

Comment: MACRO 1:
Worksheets("Excel Inputs").Activate
If Sheets("Excel Inputs").Cells(11, "P") = 3 Then
Sheets("Valuation 02").Delete
Sheets("Valuation 03").Delete
ElseIf Sheets("Excel Inputs").Cells(11, "P") = 2 Then
Sheets("Valuation 02").Delete
End If
length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B13:B15"))
For i = 1 To length - 1
Sheets("Valuation 01").Copy After:=Sheets(4 + i)
Sheets(4 + i + 1).name = "Valuation 0" & (i + 1)
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Next i
Sheets("Excel Inputs").Cells(11, "P") = length
End Sub

Comment: please see my answer, there are a few things you have to make sure. 1. All #Values are set to values ( data are ready from UDF, RTD, worksheet Functions) using the `Application.calculateFull` 
2. Knowing when the data are ready by checking the values periodic.

Comment: Instead of `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`, try `Sheets(4 + i + 1).Calculate`!  Do you use any external functions/databases that calculate a long time/refresh in the background?

Comment: No i am not using any external database.. I think the problem here is the indirect function which is being copied into various sheets by the macro..

Answer (score 0):

Usually I will use `Application.onTime Now + TimeValue("hh:mm:ss"),"macro2"`
to solve this kind of issue.  You can set macro2 to run with some delay to macro1.

And make sure at the end of your macro1,
 `Application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`  or  `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`

If this method is not good enough, you have to use a cell or a global variable as the watchman to determine if all calculations are complete.
For example, in the end of marco1, keep using `Application.onTime` event to check for some cell value <> "" 
and if not yet complete, recursive calling itself.

Reference: [Application.OnTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx)  [Application.CalculateFullRebuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb223213%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: just tried that.. still have to use shift+f9// i would like to mention that the formulae in the copied sheets use indirect function with the names of the copied sheets. can that be an issue ?

Comment: For forcing calcuation in excel. you can see http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm

Put them at the end of your macro1.